# Why in CSS, image is rounded only around border?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider these two scenarios
**Case 1:** Adding `border-radius` to image

```html
<style>

  .border {
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    
    
  }
  .image {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius:10px;
  }
</style>



  <a href="#"><img class="image border" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>
```

**2. Case 2** : Adding `border-radius` to border

```html
 
<style>

  .border {
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius:10px;
    
  }
  .image {
    width: 100px;
    
  }
</style>



  <a href="#"><img class="image border" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>
```

- Why are both scenarios same?

What I expected to see was  -

```
Case 1: image rounded but border sharp
Case 2: border rounded image sharp
```

But output is

```
Case 1: border rounded image sharp
Case 2: border rounded image sharp
```

Comment: Both your `border` and `image` classes are on the same element, so they will each affect the image. (Effectively you could just have 1 class and all the styles and achieve the same thing)

Comment: @DBS yes both classes are on same element, but then does that mean the behavior should be same?

Comment: @DBS why my expectation of `image rounded but border sharp` is not coming?

Comment: When you have multiple classes on an element, the styles are combined (There's a bit of complexity here based on specificity, but in this case just imagine they are added together) To achieve what you are describing you will probably need a wrapping element, and to apply the styles separately.

Comment: @DBS can you explain the why are they combining? Is it related to cascading ?

Comment: you have **one** element so the result should always be the same if you apply the same CSS which is the case here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your classnames are on the same DOM element, so the browser combines the rules from both classes; therefore both of your examples end up boiling down to the same code:

```css
  img {
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius:10px;
  }
```

```html
  <a href="#"><img class="image border" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>
```

If you want to be able to style the border and the image separately, you'll need to apply the css rules to different elements. In the below examples I moved the "border" to the containing `a` element.

Here's the "square image with rounded border":

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
}

.border {
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* extra css to set the display of <a>, and to remove line-height whitespace: */
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="border"><img class="image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>
```

...and here's the square border with rounded image:

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.border {
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 10px;
  /* extra css to set the display of <a>, and to remove line-height whitespace: */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  /* More extra css to fill in the corners revealed by the rounded image: */
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="border"><img class="image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I expected to see was -
>
> *Case 1*: image rounded but border sharp

If we take a look at the inspector:

[image]

We can see that both the `image` and `border` class are applyd to the `<img>`.

Since the border is rounded, the image won't have any rounded corners, just the border.

To apply the rounding to the image, consider removing the `.border` so we only apply a `border-radius` to the image:

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img class="image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>
```

---

To get an non-rounded border around the image, we can keep the border class but move it to a wrapper element:

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
.border {
  border: 5px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class='border'><img class="image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the image in a div with class border.

With `border-radius` applied to border:

```html
<style>

  .border {
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    
  }
  .image {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius:10px;
  }
</style>



  <a href="#"><div class="border"><img class="image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></div></a>
```

With `border-radius` applied to image:

```css
  .border {
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius:10px;
  }
  .image {
    width: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class="border"><img class="image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image's outline will get rounded if you just increase the radius of the rounding. Because the border-width was the same as the border-radius, the image was not getting rounded.

```html
<style>
  .border {
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
  }
  
  .image {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
</style>

<a href="#"><img class="border image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>
```

That said, your understanding of CSS seems fundamentally flawed. If an element (eg, `<img>`) has two classes (eg, `border` and `image`) then they are both applied (`<img>` has style from both `border` and `image`, regardless of the class names).

Answer (score -1):

```css
  .border {
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    
    
  }
  .image {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius:60px;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#"><img class="image border" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>
```

try this